# Parsedate question in Perl

Tags: perl

In Perl, why I get different results from parsedate(2010-7-2 13:0:0) and parsedate(2010-7-2 13:00:0) ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `2010-7-2 13:0:0` string is not in a valid format, and is actually not being parsed at all (it appears) as evidenced by the fact that `parsedate("2010-7-2")` returns the same value as `parsedate("2010-7-2 13:0:0")` for me.

Based on [the docs](http://search.cpan.org/~muir/Time-modules-2003.0211/lib/Time/ParseDate.pm), it's simply parsing the YYYY-MM-DD, but not parsing the `13:0:0` at all because it is expecting it to be in HH:MM format and not HH:M format. Basically, you have to use two digits for the minutes in order for it to be valid input.

Answer (score 0):

To handle your date format with more flexibility, try using DateTime::Format::Strptime

```
my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern   => '%Y-%m-%d %T',
    locale    => 'en_AU',
    time_zone => 'Australia/Melbourne',
);

my $dt1 = $strp->parse_datetime('2010-7-2 13:0:0');
my $date_1 = $strp->format_datetime($dt1);
```

$date_1 is now converted into a well-formatted date format "2010-07-02 13:00:00". Then you can call parsedate($date_1) & get epoch.